# Bootstrap Navbar overlap using transforms in Safari

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, css-transforms

I'm struggling with the problem of a transformed div overlapping a bootstraped navbar, illustrated below. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

It happens in safari but **not** in Firefox or Chrome. It also doesn't happen when there are no transforms applied to the div.

I'm using bootstrap 4 and tailwind.css. I've included the code below. Thanks.

Grateful for any pointers, thanks.

[image]

```
<head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
  
<nav class="navbar w-100 navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-warning fixed-top " style="background-color: #eee;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        Logo
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
            <a href="" class="effect3 nav-item nav-link">nav item</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  
<body>
    <div class="column p-0 place-self-center">
        <div class="card bg-transparent border-0 ">
            <div class="w-50 border-2 border-yellow-400 rounded-t-lg rounded-b-lg h-96 bg-dark pb-0" style="transform: perspective(150rem) rotateY(-25deg); box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px #888888;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
```

Comment: It's the `rotateY()`  thats causing the issue. I just don't know how to get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. You have to add `position` and `z-index` in the parent element `.place-self-center` and its child element `.place-self-center .bg-transparent`.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/Lj482t1p/2/

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much.
Any idea how you'd keep the ability to scroll within the div. With the z-index now being set to -1 means it'll lose the scroll.

Comment: It may be a separate question to be fair, but i've included the issue in a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/86q70sbj/

Comment: We have updated our code as per your requirement. Can you please check updated code link?